# What is the correct way to use of isWrapperFor and unwrap functions in JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc

I would like to know the correct way to validate `isWrapperFor` and unwrap functions in JDBC. Here `HIRAConnection` and the standard `Connection` classes are used.

```
HIRAConnection hiraCon1 = (HIRAConnection) ds.getConnection();
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
if (hiraCon1 instanceof Wrapper) {
    // try to use java 6 unwrapping
    try {
        Wrapper w = conn;
        if (hiraCon1.isWrapperFor(Connection.class)) {
            hiraCon1 = conn.unwrap(HIRAConnection.class); 
            hiraCon1= hiraCon1.unwrap(HIRAConnection.class);
            hiraCon1= ds.unwrap(HIRAConnection.class);//returns SQLException   
        }
        if (hiraCon1.isWrapperFor(HIRAConnection.class)) {
            hiraCon1 = conn.unwrap(HIRAConnection.class);
            hiraCon1 = hiraCon1.unwrap(HIRAConnection.class);    
        }
        if (conn.isWrapperFor(com.hira.HIRAConnection.class)) {          
            hiraCon1 = conn.unwrap(com.hira.HIRAConnection.class);
        } 
        if (conn.isWrapperFor(Connection.class)) {          
            hiraCon1 = conn.unwrap(com.hira.HIRAConnection.class);
        } 
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("Failed to unwrap connection using java 6 facilities");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to use `java.sql.Wrapper` is documented in its javadoc.

For [`isWrapperFor(Class<?> iface)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Wrapper.html#isWrapperFor(java.lang.Class)):

> Returns true if this either implements the interface argument or is
>   directly or indirectly a wrapper for an object that does. Returns
>   false otherwise. If this implements the interface then return true,
>   else if this is a wrapper then return the result of recursively
>   calling `isWrapperFor` on the wrapped object. If this does not
>   implement the interface and is not a wrapper, return false. This
>   method should be implemented as a low-cost operation compared to
>   `unwrap` so that callers can use this method to avoid expensive `unwrap`
>   calls that may fail. If this method returns true then calling `unwrap`
>   with the same argument should succeed.
>
> **Parameters**:
>       `iface` - a Class defining an interface.
>   **Returns**:
>       true if this implements the interface or directly or indirectly wraps an object that does.

And for [`unwrap(Class<T> iface)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Wrapper.html#unwrap(java.lang.Class)):

> Returns an object that implements the given interface to allow access
>   to non-standard methods, or standard methods not exposed by the proxy.
>   If the receiver implements the interface then the result is the
>   receiver or a proxy for the receiver. If the receiver is a wrapper and
>   the wrapped object implements the interface then the result is the
>   wrapped object or a proxy for the wrapped object. Otherwise return the
>   the result of calling `unwrap` recursively on the wrapped object or a
>   proxy for that result. If the receiver is not a wrapper and does not
>   implement the interface, then an `SQLException` is thrown.
>
> **Type Parameters**:
>       `T` - the type of the class modeled by this Class object
>   **Parameters**:
>       `iface` - A Class defining an interface that the result must implement.
>   **Returns**:
>       an object that implements the interface. May be a proxy for the actual implementing object.
>   **Throws**:
>       `SQLException` - If no object found that implements the interface

In other words, you can first check using `wrapperFor` if the wrapper can unwrap to the interface, and then you can use `unwrap` to really unwrap to that interface. Be aware that the specification only mentions support to unwrap to interface, so unwrapping to concrete classes may not actually be possible.

Whether this works, depends on the driver used (not all drivers support unwrapping or maybe they have nothing useful to unwrap), and if you are using a connection pool library, then it is entirely possible that it doesn't allow you to unwrap to - for example - the underlying connection, because doing that could allow you to circumvent or break certain limits and requirements of the connection pool.

So the correct way to use wrapping would be:

```
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
if (conn.isWrapperFor(HiraConnection.class)) {
    HIRAConnection hiraCon1 = conn.unwrap(HiraConnection.class);
    // use hiraCon1...
)
```

However if `HiraConnection` is a concrete class instead of an interface, this might not work. And unwrapping will usually also lead to brittle code. It is usually better to avoid relying on driver specific interface unless absolutely necessary.

Some remarks on the code in your question:

- If you know `HIRAConnection hiraCon1 = (HIRAConnection) ds.getConnection();` works, then you don't need to unwrap at all.
- Checking for `hiraCon1 instanceof Wrapper` is a useless check, because if `HIRAConnection` implements `java.sql.Connection`, then it will always implement `java.sql.Wrapper` (and otherwise running your code would yield a `ClassNotFoundException` for `java.sql.Wrapper` meaning you ran it on Java 5 or lower).
- Checking `hiraCon1.isWrapperFor(Connection.class)` and then unwrapping `conn` to `HIRAConnection` is unsafe and makes no sense. If you want to unwrap `conn` to `HIRAConnection`, then you need to use `conn.isWrapperFor(HiraConnection.class)`
- It is not unexpected that `hiraCon1= ds.unwrap(HIRAConnection.class);` throws an `SQLException`: it is unlikely that a `javax.sql.DataSource` implementation considers itself a wrapper for connections.
- Checking `hiraCon1.isWrapperFor(HIRAConnection.class)` is a bit odd: you already know `hiraCon1` **is** a `HIRAConnection`
- As previously mentioned, unwrapping `conn` after checking `hiraCon1` makes no sense.
- Checking `conn.isWrapperFor(Connection.class)` is a bit odd: you already know `conn` **is** a `Connection`
- Checking `conn.isWrapperFor(Connection.class)` and then using `conn.unwrap(com.hira.HIRAConnection.class)` is unsafe, as you have only checked whether `conn` unwraps to `Connection`, not to `HIRAConnection`.

Comment: @SelimAlawwa If you have a new question, then please post a new question (and definitely don't bother people on other platforms like LinkedIn).